# what's the purpose to set the parent location?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe embedded in the page. Why we need to set the perent location Href from the iframe, any reason for that?

```
self.parent.location.href = blah blah blah;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's usually a frame breaker technique.

Usually something like this:

```
if(self != top)top.location.href=someUrl;
```

Comment: can you explain in more detailed way, I am new to this area?

Answer (score 0):

As it's possible to put an iframe tag inside your page's body, you use `top` to manipulate the main window. See:

**Main page**

```
<!--This is the main page-->
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        alert(window.top.location.href);//The main page's URL
        alert(window.self.location.href);//The main page's URL
        alert(window.top.location.href);//The main page's URL
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="myFrame.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myFrame.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        alert(window.location.href);//"myFrame.html"
        alert(window.self.location.href);//"myFrame.html"
        alert(window.top.location.href);//The main page's URL
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```